# Increase the array size of a user defined data type in java

Tags: java, arrays, custom-data-type

I created a data type in java like this   (just a trivial example)...

```
public class Car{  
  public String color;
  public String Brand;
}
```

After that I created an array with several instances, two to be exact...

```
Car[] car = new Car[2];    
car[0] = new Car();  
car[0].color = "Red";  
car[0].brand = "Ford";  
car[1] = new Car();  
car[1].color = "Blue";  
car[1].brand = "BMW";
```

And now my question. What if after that I face a situation in which I need to add a new car? How can I increase the size of the car variable?

Thanks in advance for your help and patience!

Comment: Java offers you collection framework. Choose any type of collection that suits your need and add Car object to it. You can make Set of cars, Map of cars, List of cars etc. Google for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `ArrayList` instead of a plain array: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html.